# "FAILED Error performing request" when pushing application to Cloud Foundry on Azure BOSH

Tags: azure, cloud-foundry

I'm new in Cloud Foundry and I decided to try it. I deployed BOSH to azure using docs https://github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/bosh-azure-cpi-release/blob/master/docs/guidance.md

Everything was passed well. Now I'm trying to deploy my first application and I'm having problems. I'm using this doc 
https://github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/bosh-azure-cpi-release/blob/master/docs/get-started/push-demo-app.md.

I can't pass the first step:

```
adminCF@cf-test:~$ cat ~/settings | grep cf-ip
    "cf-ip": "104.40.216.252",

adminCF@cf-test:~$ cf login -a https://api.104.40.216.252.xip.io --skip-ssl-validation  
API endpoint: https://api.104.40.216.252.xip.io  
FAILED Error performing request: Get https://api.104.40.216.252.xip.io/v2/info: dial tcp
104.40.216.252:443: i/o timeout TIP: If you are behind a firewall and require an HTTP proxy, verify the https_proxy environment variable is correctly set. Else, check your network connection.  

adminCF@cf-test:~$ cf login -a https://api.104.40.216.252.xip.io --skip-ssl-validation 
-u admin -p ******  
API endpoint: https://api.104.40.216.252.xip.io  
FAILED Error performing request: Get https://api.104.40.216.252.xip.io/v2/info: dial tcp
104.40.216.252:443: i/o timeout TIP: If you are behind a firewall and require an HTTP proxy, verify the https_proxy environment variable is correctly set. Else, check your network connection.   

adminCF@cf-test:~$
```

Comment: All I can really say with the given information is that your system can't make a connection to the API.  As stated in the error, you may need to setup an HTTP proxy.  If that's not the case, then it's more likely that something is not  working properly with your Cloud Foundry install.  There's not enough information here to say what.  You can include information like `bosh deployments` and `bosh vms` to give some indication as to the status of what you've deployed.  The former provides version numbers, the latter provides status of bosh deployed VMs.  Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi, Daniel. Thank u for ur reply. I hadn't done all steps from instruction. Now it works. but I have another question about pushing application. I need configure my space:cf target -o "REPLACE_WITH_CLOUD_FOUNDRY_PUBLIC_IP.xip.io_ORGANIZATION" -s "azure". What is ORGANIZATION and where can I see this value?